# Cytoscape gives extension error for GML files from Networkx

Tags: networkx, cytoscape

I cannot open any GML files with Cytoscape and I keep getting "wrong extension" errors whether I use  ".gml" or no extension at all.

Cytoscape 3.8 using Java 11 on an Ubuntu machine. The files are written by the `write_gml` function of `networkx`.

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to import GML files as a session.

To import GML files you should do the following:

- From the main menu select 'Import > Network from File...'
- Select the GML format.
- Select your file and click on 'Open'

Comment: Meh, I was using Ctrl+O.